# Linked list shows only first node element on printing

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I am trying to create a linked list in order to enhance my concepts of pointers and address. I have to create linked list in following way:

(1) Read all the nodes together at once at terminal.

(2) Then show the final linked list so formed at last.

How i try to do so ?
I am reading first the size of linked list (total number of nodes to be entered). Then i read all the nodes 1 by one in `do-while` loop. After reading all the nodes i try to create linked list. I differentiate the case when the node is first node to be created by a `count` variable which will have `count=0` when the node is first node after that it will be in another loop.

The output i get is as follows:

```
 enter the size of node
4
start entering the number of elements until your size
2
3
4
5
Printing linked list
2-> //It don't print the other nodes, Just first one
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/pointer$
```

My full code to do so is :

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <malloc.h> 
#include <string.h>

struct node 
{
    int freq;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node;
node * tree;

void main() 
{
    int size, data;
    int count = 0; //this count flag is to check is it's first node or not inside the do-while loop.
    tree = NULL;
    printf("enter the size of node\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    printf("start entering the number of elements until your size\n");
    node * temp3 = tree;
    node * prev;
    //Problem creating area is below
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", & data);
        if (count == 0)
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp-> freq = data;
            temp-> next = NULL;
            prev = temp;
        } 
        else if (count != 0) 
        {
            node * temp;
            temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp-> freq = data;
            temp-> next = NULL;
            prev-> next = temp;
        }
        size--;
        ++count;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    printf("Printing linked list\n");
    node * temp1;
    temp1 = prev;
    //there may be problem here
    while (temp1-> next != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%d-> ", temp1-> freq);
        temp1 = temp1-> next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Couldanyone please help me in printing the full linked list by pointing me the error with  it's solution ?

Comment: A few notes here: main should return something or be set to void, you have by my count three unused pointers (tree, temp3, and store), and in your else if, you are setting the prev node to temp, and then allocating memory for temp and basically overwriting what it is pointed to.

Comment: Debugger, debgugger, debugger...

Comment: @JamesHostick I have kept the void main() in my edit. But the problem is how to avoid this overwritting of nodes because i am reading all nodes together

Comment: I'll say start with splitting the lots of code into multiple functions .

Comment: And also, best not to use void main(), just use int main().

Comment: It's a bit confusing that you are relying on `prev` to point to the first element. It actually does here, but shouldn't it really be updated to the value of `temp` and so be pointing at the previous element, as the name suggests?

Comment: @JamesHostick Thanks i have removed "node * temp= prev;" in "else if" condition even then it prints the first node.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError sorry i couldn't understand , Could you please explain more in detail ?

Comment: Actually Archa's answer below shows what I was getting at.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError this "start" poiner variable must be "temp" in my case (if i declare node*temp) outside the do-while loop? I tried that in this case it even don't print the first node (prints nothing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay there is some unnecessary pointers and a few pointer mistakes being made, for ease of answering I've rewritten your code, I'll try to explain what I did here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    int freq;
    struct node * next;
};
typedef struct node node;
//only need two pointers when building a linked list, one for the top and one for the
//current node
node *tree = NULL, *curr = NULL; //init both pointers to NULL initially

int main()
{
    int size, data; //dont need count, you'll see in a minute why
    printf("enter the size of node\n");
    scanf("%d", & size);
    printf("start entering the number of elements until your size\n");

    //Problem creating area is below
    do
    {
        scanf("%d", &data);
        if (tree == NULL) //just test for top node being NULL instead of using count
        {
            node *temp;
            temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->freq = data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            //stylistically i like using curr rather than prev, just a style choice
            tree = temp; //set tree to first node
            curr = tree; //make the top node the current node
        }
        else //don't need else if, there are only two conditions
        {
            node *temp = malloc(sizeof(node));
            temp->freq = data;
            temp->next = NULL;
            curr->next = temp; //set the next node in list to the new one
            curr = curr->next; //here's where you had pointer issues, move the current
                               //to the newly created node
        }
        size--;
    }
    while (size > 0);

    printf("Printing linked list\n");
    curr = tree; //reuse curr, no need to make a new pointer

    //test for the current node being NULL, takes care of special case of empty list
    //causing a segfault when you attempt to access a member of an invalid pointer
    while (curr != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->", curr->freq);
        curr = curr->next; //move to next item in list
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I ran a sample run with size of 3 and inputs of 1, 2, and 3, and I get as output: 1->2->3->

Comment: I didn't do any error testing with the mallocs, but it is good practice to immediately test the pointer after malloc to ensure that it allocated memory, otherwise you should print some sort of error message.

Comment: No problem, I love pointers, I hate pointers, and I love to hate pointers.

Comment: why we need to move cur to new node by doing this "curr = curr->next"? we have already established the link of cur to new node by the line "curr->next = temp;" this step should be enough to join the link between the two nodes. could you please explain a bit  more in detail ?Thanks

Comment: the purpose of curr is to keep track of where you currently are in the list. the line curr->next = temp adds the newly created node to the end of the list. Then curr = curr->next moves your current position to the last node in the list, that is, the new node we just appended to the end of the list. Otherwise you will end up overwriting the current node rather than appending to the end (which is why you ended up with only one node in the list, regardless of how many elements you had the user enter).

Comment: @JamesHostick thanks one more doubt, what is the difference between while (curr != NULL) and while (curr->next!= NULL)?, I tried to know by printing the results so in the case of while (curr->next != NULL) it don't print the last element. But it was supposed to be do that because we are doing until the next of the last node is not NULL.

Comment: Takes care of special case of the list being empty (top being null) otherwise if the list is empty you will have a problem when trying to say temp->anything because the pointer won't be valid

Answer (score 2):

You got two problems.

```
else if (count != 0) 
    {
        node * temp = prev;
        temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp-> freq = data;
        temp-> next = NULL;
        prev-> next = temp;
    }
```

You aren't changing prev to point to your new node.  It still points to '2' in your scenario, and you'll never have more than two nodes in the list.

Try something like

```
else if (count != 0) 
    {
        /* node * temp = prev; */ //This code is not doing anything useful
        temp = (node * ) malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp-> freq = data;
        temp-> next = NULL;
        prev-> next = temp;
        prev = temp;
    }
```

Next, your printing loop should probably be

```
node* temp1 = start; //You need a variable that points to the first node in the list
do 
{
    printf("%d-> ", temp1-> freq);
    temp1 = temp1-> next;
} 
//The last item will always have next == NULL, and must be included
while (temp1-> next != NULL);
```

Comment: One note here for the third block of code, when accessing members of a struct pointer, you should check to make sure the pointer is valid before doing accessing. Otherwise you'll get a segfault. Chances are it won't as long as start is a valid pointer, but you can never be sure that the user didn't mess something up. :)

Comment: @Archa Thanks but i tried both you just said , None of them worked

Comment: I am not using "start" , I am using "tree".